# How to do UX for people to use a widget

Tags: widgets

I have a site that helps people organize hikes.  Here is a typical hike page:

http://www.comehike.com/hikes/scheduled_hike.php?hike_id=174

I made a widget for people to be able to share their hikes.  Here is the widget for the same hike:

http://www.comehike.com/outdoors/widget.php?hike_id=174&height=500&width=700

But I am really stuck on how to get my users to understand that they can export their hike as a widget and share it.  Plus, what phrasing should I use? "Share your hike" or "make the map into a sharable link" ?

Are there any good examples of such UX and wording?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would copy Google maps as people are going to be familiar with that. They have the chain icon and the word "link". Then when you click link you get

```
Paste link in email or IM
(Text box)
Paste HTML to embed in website
(Text box)
Customise and preview embedded map (link)
```